# Alternative sin() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

for compatibility reasons with an existing library, I need a sin() (**and cos()**) function that

```
Returns the cosine of x, where 1.0 indicates a full circle
    sin is inverted to suit screenspace
    e.g. sin(0.25) returns -1
```

From the examples I have:

```
sin(0)   = 0
sin(0.1) = -0.5877
sin(0.2) = -0.9511
sin(0.3) = -0.9511
sin(0.4) = -0.5877
sin(0.5) = 0 
sin(0.6) = 0.5877
sin(0.7) = 0.9511
sin(0.8) = 0.9511
sin(0.9) = 0.5877
sin(1)   = -1
```

How do I write such functions in Javascript?
Thanks

Comment: [Math.sin()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the existing function **Math.sin()** and **Math.cos()**
if you want to initial convert of 1 to 1*Pi do this:

```
function sin(a){
return Math.sin(Math.PI*a);
}

function cos(a){
return Math.cos(Math.PI*a);
}
```

and if you want 1 to be assumed as a full circle (why?!), use `Math.sin(Math.PI*2*a)`

Comment: he needs both Sin and Cos function i believe.